# Every complex 1-manifold is Kähler.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I want to prove that every complex 1-dimensional manifold $X$ admits a Kähler form. My idea is to construct the Kähler form by
$$ \omega = i \partial \bar \partial \phi $$
where $\phi$ is some real-valued function. Then one has that $\omega$ is a real $(1,1)$-form and that it is closed. However, it is not necessarily positive; its coordinate representation is
$$ \omega = i \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial \bar z} \phi\ dz \wedge d \bar z $$
where I noticed that $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial \bar z} = \frac{1}{4} (\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2})$. For $\omega$ to be positive, one needs that $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial \bar z} \phi > 0$. I don't think a real-valued function with positive laplacian exists on every 1-dimensional complex manifold, or does it?

One thing I noticed is that, if $f$ is holomorphic, then $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial \bar z} (f \bar f) = |\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}|^2 \geq 0$, but then again, compact complex manifolds don't even have non-constant holomorphic functions.

Could someone tell if this type of argument is salvageable, and if not, how one would prove this fact otherwise?

Comment: Do you know that a complex structure on a surface is equivalent to a conformal structure?

Comment: No. In fact, I don't even know what a conformal structure is.

Comment: A conformal structure is an equivalence class of Riemannian metrics. You declare two metrics to be conformally equivalent if there exists an $f:\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g=fg'$. It then turns out that on a surface, you can define the complex structure to be the Hodge star operator associated to the conformal structure (which is well-defined). The Hodge star operator $\star:T\Sigma\to T\Sigma$ preserves the metric, i.e. $g(\star v,\star w)=g(v,w)$. This would be one approach to the problem.

Comment: This is a bad approach. In particular, if your manifold is compact, the Kähler form cannot possibly be exact.

Comment: Have you checked what happens if you pick a Hermitian metric on the manifold and check whether its $(1,1)$-form is closed?

Comment: Cant you just show that the form $\omega(X,Y)=g(\star X,Y)$ is symplectic and $\star$ defines an integrable complex structure for dimensional reasons?